# Flatlist event when start reached

Tags: react-native

How we can implement **onStartReached** in **FlatList** ?
I used horizontal list.
I have some idea of using **onScroll** using,but I thing this not properly.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems onRefresh could do the job.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh

it must be start reached and pull to trigger onRefresh.

Answer (score -2):

If you need a infinite scroll i used this

```
<FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
          // Component to render
        );
      }}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.uid}
      onEndReached={() => //Load more data}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} // "Sleep" time
      initialNumToRender={10} // initial number to items
    />
```

otherwise the way to use onStartReached is identical to onEndReached

Comment: So Flatlist has onStartReached event? Why I can't find infos about that =(

Comment: Oh Sorry, I read the documentation and the FlatList dont have onStartReached event :c but maybe you can use pan responder (? sorry :c